# How to find an Element by index in selenium webdriver for java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to automate the Google Images page:

https://www.google.com/search?q=pluralsight&biw=1416&bih=685&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=qGd6VN6bEZTooAT7q4C4BQ&sqi=2&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAw

All the images have the same class but no id and the results are constantly changing.  So I would like to be able to click on the images based on their index.

I know how to do it in C#...but I cant figure out how to specify in the index in Java.  When I try to select an index beyond 0, I get and IndexOutOfBounds error, but i cant figure out why

```
WebElement image = chromeDriver.findElement(By.className("rg_di"));
WebElement imageLink = image.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(1);
imageLink.click();
```

Here is the entire code im using...any help would be appreciated:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/user/chromedriver");
    WebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    chromeDriver.get("http://www.google.com");

    WebElement searchBox = chromeDriver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq"));
    searchBox.sendKeys("pluralsight");
    searchBox.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);

    chromeDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebElement imagesLink = chromeDriver.findElement(By.linkText("Images"));
    imagesLink.click();

    WebElement image = chromeDriver.findElement(By.className("rg_di"));
    WebElement imageLink = image.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(1);
    imageLink.click();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code:

```
WebElement image = chromeDriver.findElement(By.className("rg_di"));
```

will return the first element found on the page with a class of "rg_di".

That element has only one `<a href=... /a>` tag in it.

You are getting an IndexOutOfBounds exception because you are asking for the *second* one (zero based indexing).  If you change your final WebElement to:

```
WebElement imageLink = image.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(0);
```

The code should work for you with that small change.

This is my quick version (note the lack of storing elements I only need to do one thing with as WebElements):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // I don't have Chrome installed >.<
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq"));
    searchBox.sendKeys("pluralsight");
    searchBox.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Images")).click();

    WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.className("rg_di"));
    image.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(0).click();

    // super-shortened version:
    // driver.findElement(By.className("rg_di")).findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(0).click();
}
```

Comment: Yes i updated the code to use the id of the ordered list that all of the image links are in...so now i can get to each of them by index

Answer (score 3):

I'd do:

```
List<WebElement> we  = chromeDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".your-class a"));

we.get(1) //should get first element in array
```

Answer (score 2):

This code worked very well when we have similar object properties for same web buttons, then using

```
List<WebElement> we = webdriver.findElements(By.cssSelector(""));
```

and then getting

```
 we.get(1).click();
```

Thank you so much for posting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution may be like this:
If the class name and the index of the web element are known, then following code works:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='android.widget.ImageView'])[18]")).click();
```