# How to find Element [For Selenium]

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am practicing Selenium using Java Eclipse. I want to be able to log into Twitter using Selenium. I don't see any element associated with the username and password fields though. Why is that are no elements?  How can I access these fields?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find an Element by index in selenium webdriver for java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208872/how-to-find-an-element-by-index-in-selenium-webdriver-for-java)

Comment: What is wrong with the `class` and `name` attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xpath as below. These expressions are working form me.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("https://twitter.com/login");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='signin-wrapper']//input[@name='session[username_or_email]']")).sendKeys("Yourusername");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='signin-wrapper']//input[@name='session[password]']")).sendKeys("YourPassword");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Log in')]")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This was really helpful @Maninder!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply access those fields with `XPath`:

```
//input[@placeholder="Phone, email or username"]
//input[@placeholder="Password"]
```

Let me know if for some reason you cannot use these selectors or in case of any exceptions ocurred

Comment: Thanks Andersson! Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to find the XPath:
In chrome, click Inspect on the element of interest. You will have the option of copying the XPath from there. Image attached for reference: [image]

Answer (score -1):

Please use the xpath as below. we can able to access that.

(//*[@name='session[username_or_email]'])[2]

Comment: Thanks Ramesh! Appreciate your help!